# PDF URL Redirection

Tags: apache-httpd

I was looking answer for mentioned query. Could you please have a look at my query and suggest. product has provided URL something like mentioned below which i need to redirect on other domains(test.com/index.html). 
When i open these URL i got error Cannot Open File. How do i redirect these:

```
"www.abc.com/work/file?cmsid=2db1526745e94d57b90a1410b336e62d" 
"www.abc.com/work/file?cmsid=fd84932d9b1742aea70f5a3f379ca661"
"www.abc.com/work/file?cmsid=6245d97596f24c6d9d89fb0f6c24deg7"
"www.abc.com/work/file?cmsid=ddf2fb1d2f194b249f4ea5cbd848337f"
```

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # not a dir    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # not a file
RewriteRule "/work/file?cmsid=2db1526745e94d57b90a1410b336e62d" "https://example.com/product/index.html" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [unix.se]. I've edited your question to fix the formatting as best I could. Please use the { } button above the editor to format pasted configuration, etc. Also, please [edit] your question if I've made a mistake, I unwrapped the RewriteRule line for example. Also, your example URLs, should they start with `http://` or `https://` ?

Comment: Also, could you clarify — are you trying to send any request for that file (regardless of the cmsid) to index.html? Or only when `cmsid=2db1526745e94d57b90a1410b336e62d` ?

Comment: Product has provided URL https://www.abc.com/work/file?cmsid=6ad51b370c914a6082c8776a68f16d3a which i need to redirect on https://example.com/products/etp.html i have more then 1000 files which will redirect on same domain but on different path. All i have is cmsid which i will redirect on different  link. yes my example URL will start with https://

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you are approaching to this problem the right way. My suggestion would be to have some scriptable language file (php for example) that will do the redirects based on your map of 1000 files. all the requests should end up on that php scripts, and you can redirect visitors to another url from that single php.

Comment: i wish i could do but they are using only this format :(

Comment: you need to redirect all those urls to your php script:  
  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^cmsid=(.*)$    [NC]  
RewriteRule file script.php?id=%1 [NC,L,R=301]  
  
In your php script you will have something like:  
  
$ids = array(  
'2db1526745e94d57b90a1410b336e62d'=>'https://example.com/product/index.html',  
'someotherid'=>'sometherurl'...);  
  
header('Location: '.echo $ids[$_GET['id']]);  
exit;

Comment: Thanks and i appreciate. i will try this.